# Laravel 8 factory state function counting up

Tags: laravel, laravel-factory

I have a laravel 8 project and want to seed a model that should contain several `datasheets` with the `dayOfMonth`-property ranging from 1 to 25

```
class DatabaseSeeder extends Seeder
{
    /**
     * Run the database seeders.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {
       User::factory()
                  ->count(30)
                  ->has(DataSheet::factory()
                                        ->count(25)
                                        ->state(function (array $attributes, DataSheet $dataSheet) {
                                                                                    return [
                                                                                        'data_sheet_id' => $dataSheet->id,
                                                                                        'dayOfMonth' =>  // values counted from 1 to 25
                                                                                    ];
                                                                                })
    }
}
```

How do I implement the dayOfMonth part?

Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use faker's

by adding `$faker->unique()->numberBetween(1,25),`

Comment: Thanks for your answer! First of all, I do not know how to get a $faker instance in the seeder. Sadly, even if I knew, I don't think that this works, because it will just generate a random number, which was not what I was looking for